# Passing values to a variable for plotting live charts in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am making a dashboard in which I will be plotting a live chart using Highcharts and an offline json file named PeakVibrations.json which is stored in the same directory as the webpage for the dashboard.

I have a JSON File named PeakVibrations1.json of 101 records , the following is a subset of the data :

```
[
  { "PeakVibrationafterAssembly" : "5.1"},
  { "PeakVibrationafterAssembly" : "3"},
  { "PeakVibrationafterAssembly" : "4.3"},
  { "PeakVibrationafterAssembly" : "2.0"}
]
```

I have pre processed the json file using the snippet given on the highcharts site:

```
 $.getJSON('PeakVibrations1.json', function(data) {
    options.series[0].data = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
 });
```

I have taken the code for generating live random data                       (link is https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update)  and as i had to pass the json file data to the chart instead of the random data i made few changes,
The code for the live chart that i need to make in highcharts is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = json.parse(data);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'VibrationValue'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Live data',
        data: (function () {
            // pass value to x and y
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: json.parsedata()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});  });
```

But the chart is not being plotted.
As far as I can speculate , I am facing problem in assigning the json file, values to the variable "y" in highcharts code
Any help would be of great assistance

Could anyone suggest some better method to do this?

Comment: Your code and description does not allow to answer the question. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How do you send the variable to the client? What is your chart config? Sample of the csv file would be helpful as well.

Comment: @morganfree  I have updated the question , waiting for your kind referral to my problem. Thank You

Comment: addPoint() adds just one point, if you have json with multiple points you need to use methods like series.setData() or series.update() - before that the json must be parsed to a correct format which can be understood by Highcharts - how the series, data and point should look like is explained here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series How to work with external data is explaine here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro. Summing up, the format for the chart's data is incorrect